# AngularJS: Trying to make filter work with delayed data

Tags: angularjs

I have this html:

```
  <div ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller='testCtrl'>
      <h3>All possesions</h3>
      {{possessions}}
      <h3>Green cars</h3>
      {{greenishCars}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

And this script:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .factory('getPossessionsService', ['$timeout',
    function($timeout) {
      var possessions = {};
      $timeout(function() {
        possessions.cars = [{
          model: "Mazda 6",
          color: "lime green"
        }, {
          model: "Audi A3",
          color: "red"
        }, {
          model: "Audi TT",
          color: "green"
        }, {
          model: "Volkswagen Lupo",
          color: "forest green"
        }];
        possessions.jewelry = [{
          type: "ring",
          metal: "gold"
        }, {
          type: "earring",
          metal: "silver"
        }];
      }, 1000);
      return possessions;
    }
  ])

.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', 'filterFilter', 'getPossessionsService',
  function($scope, filterFilter, getPossessionsService) {
    $scope.possessions = getPossessionsService;

    $scope.greenishCars = filterFilter($scope.possessions.cars, carColorIsGreenShade);

    function carColorIsGreenShade(car) {
      return ['green', 'forest green', 'lime green'].indexOf(car.color) != -1;
    }
  }
]);
```

I am trying to get $scope.greenishCars to update correctly when the data is available, but it is not. I understand that this has because $scope.possessions.cars is an array and therefore not a reference to the data, so it is not updated. But how should I alter my script so that greenishCars get updated when the data arrives? I am guessing I should use $scope.possessions "directly", but I do not quite see how I should rewrite this nicely....

See this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/0BfQ3p?p=preview).

**Edit: Thoughts on which answer to choose**
As in comments in the answers to Oliver and MajoB, I ended up with using both filter and watch. In my special case the request for the data was made in another place (not in the controller of my page in question), so it was not so easy to act on the resolving of the promise (with promise.then as suggested by Oliver), I therefore used a watch. But there is a couple of things to be aware of with watches. If the variable you want to watch is not on the scope, then you must provide the variable by returning it from a function. And if you want to watch for a change in an existing property (say somebody repaints my existing Mazda 6 in a different color), then none of the watch-answers works, as you need to add "true" when calling $watch. When you add 'true' as the second paramenter to $watch, then it watches for changes in the actual values of the variable, and it also does this check for values deeply in an object/array (without it just checks references, see [this blog](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-scope-watch-vs-watchcollection-in-angularjs.htm)). I ended up with this controller/$watch for my real-life use-case (which is a little bit different that in my example above, and is based on Olivers [filter-plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pw8NwSrzSdhG6MaWqtYU?p=preview)), and it looks like this (changed to fit the plunk):

```
.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', 'greenFilter', 'getPossessionsService',
  function($scope, greenFilter, getPossessionsService) {
    var none-scope-possessions = getPossessionsService; // I do not want to expose all properties on the scope....
    $scope.greenishCars = [];

    $scope.$watch(function() {return none-scope-possessions.cars}, function(newValue){
      if (newValue) {
        $scope.greenishCars = greenFilter(newValue);
      }
    },true);
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend just building your own custom filter like so:

```
.filter('green', function() {
  return function(possessions) {
    if (!possessions) return null;

    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(possessions, function(possesion){
      if (['green', 'forest green', 'lime green'].indexOf(possesion.color) != -1) {
        filtered.push(possesion);
      }
    });
    return filtered;
  };
})
```

Then pass your collection through that filter like so:

```
<div ng-controller='testCtrl'>
  <h3>All possesions</h3>
  {{possessions}}
  <h3>Green cars</h3>
  {{possessions.cars|green}}
</div>
```

Everything else will happen automatically. See the [updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pw8NwSrzSdhG6MaWqtYU?p=preview).

Comment: Lots of correct answer, thank you to you all! I chose creating a custom filter as this looks sexier :) And it is more general (does not have to be used only for cars), and I guess I can be a little more declarative in the html (which I imagine is a good thing).

Comment: Oh, Oliver, how can the "possessions.cars|green" be done in the controller? I have a form-fields I want to populate with cars-data. Or: How should I do this with your filter?

Comment: @EricC You can inject the filter into your controller, just like a service. Then you can just call `green(possessions.cars)`.

Comment: @EricC If you have form fields you want to populate with the filtered data, you can still use the filter in your markup. If you must use the filter programmatically, you still have to wait for the data to be available (it isn't in the plunkr). If you're retrieving via `$http`, apply the filter in your `then()` handler, otherwise use a `$watch` as suggested in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can watch the data changes:

```
$scope.$watch('possessions.cars', function(){
    $scope.greenishCars = filterFilter($scope.possessions.cars, carColorIsGreenShade);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can watch possesions collection for changes:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('possessions', function (newValue) {

  if (newValue)
  {
    $scope.greenishCars = filterFilter(newValue.cars, carColorIsGreenShade);
  }
});
```

> http://plnkr.co/edit/Sl6dW0pqKr593OXrgDb9?p=preview

Comment: what is the a reason for the "if(newValue)"? The watch callback is run when there is a change, ie there is a newValue?

Comment: @EricC there will be undefined exception if you set null to possesions but the else statement is missing in my example.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is , var possessions = {};  you have declared an object , cars is an field in this object , which has array of cars . so either return possessions.cars or in the markup call it via possessions.cars[0].. if you want to call only one value ..or if you want to display all the values the use ng-repeat=" car in possessions.cars" .